# How to check if a Map has duplicate key?

Tags: java, dictionary

Ok so here's what I have to do:

Split the passed `List` into individual lines, and then split those lines using a delimiter and then add those parts to a `Map`.

My code:

```
public GrammarSolver(List<String> rules) {
    if(rules == null || rules.size() == 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    Map<String, String> rulesMap = new HashMap<String, String>();
    Iterator<String> i = rules.iterator();
    while(i.hasNext()) {
        String rule = i.next(); // store a line from 'rules' List
        String[] parts = rule.split("::="); // split the line into non-terminal and terminal
        rulesMap.put(parts[0], parts[1]); // Put the two parts into the map
    }
    // TODO: exception when duplicate key in map
}
```

Everything works fine, but now my assignment says that I need to throw an exception if the key of any line is duplicated (occurring more than once).

From what I understand, keys can only be unique, so what am I missing here?

Comment: see: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html#containsKey%28java.lang.Object%29

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Keys are unique once added to the `HashMap`, but you can know if the next one you are going to add is already present by querying the hash map with `containsKey(..)` or `get(..)` method.

Comment: So what if I have a key called `key1' in my `HashMap`, and I am trying to add another one with same name, what happens?

Comment: I guess you should read it by yourself in documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#put(K, V).

Comment: So the value for a key is overwritten if I pass in another value for the same key, and the method returns the new value?

Answer (score 1):

just add the exception to the line

```
rulesMap.put(parts[0], parts[1]); // Put the two parts into the map
```

like

```
// Put the two parts into the map
if((String existing = rulesMap.put(parts[0], parts[1])) != null) 
      throw new IllegalStateException(
             "duplicated key " + parts[0] 
             + " with value " + existing + " overwritten by " + parts[1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can write like below:

```
while(i.hasNext()) {
    String rule = i.next(); // store a line from 'rules' List
    String[] parts = rule.split("::="); // split the line into non-terminal and terminal
    if(rulesMap.containsKey(parts[0]){
        throw New Excpetion(...);
    }else{
        rulesMap.put(parts[0], parts[1]); // Put the two parts into the map
    }

}
```